# how to display the title of category of links

Tags: jquery, multi-level

I am using the [multi-level push menu](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/08/13/multi-level-push-menu) on a project. What I want to achieve with the navigation is when I click into one of the categories and then click on a link of a specific category it should show you what category it is on when the new page loads. At the moment what it is doing is when I click on a sub-category link under a category it resets the menu and goes back to the top level of the menu again but it still shows the url of the page in the locator.

I am trying to reference with jQuery how to do this but haven't been having any luck of late.

Here is my code sample:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.menu").click(function() {
        $("#mp-menu").show();
            localStorage.setItem("#mp-menu", true);
        });
        if (localStorage.getItem("#mp-menu")) {
            $("#mp-menu").show();
        }
});
```

Some of the html code:

```
<!-- mp-menu -->
            <nav id="mp-menu" class="mp-menu">
                <div class="mp-level">
                    <h2 class="icon icon-world">Setup</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="icon icon-arrow-left">
                            <a class="icon icon-display" href="#" class="menu">Parameters</a>
                            <div class="mp-level">
                                <h2 class="icon icon-display" class="mp-menu">Parameters</h2>
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="icon icon-arrow-left">
                                        <a class="icon icon-phone" href="parameters_country.html">Country</a>
```

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: here is a demo of it http://tympanus.net/Development/MultiLevelPushMenu/. The first option. Attention is on the menu titles. When I click on one of the links on the list it will push the menus out. But in my case. I have put links to go to a certain pages when you click on a link under a category but it just goes back to the top level menu. If you still not able to understand what I am trying to achieve. I will post a jsfiddle of my code later today.